# How is base income calculated in Greed Corp?

Tags: greed-corp

In the first few turns, there is a base income of 10 gold per turn. Later, this rises steadily, but how exactly is the value calculated? Does it simply increase after a certain number of turns, or does it depend on the player's actions in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented with the game for some time. It solely depends on the number of left tiles (which we shall call L), with the base income equal to 40 minus L, but at least 10. The maximum possible while the game is still ongoing is thus 38 (with 2 players).

I have found that any of the following make no difference

- maps of different shape and size
- small/large number of walkers for one or any player
- number of layers left on the map
- number of neutral tiles
- number of cannons and carriers
- number of harvesters applied at the moment or in the past (note the difference between *harvester* income and *base* income)

Comment: Note: I only tried this with 2 players. I did not check it with 3 or 4, though telling from memory, it seems to behave very similarly.